# Angular store response as default json

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using angular I am creating a theming app. It has a reset theme feature, which will allow user to reset the theme to earlier. Below is my angular code so far. I have created 2 json variables in the same scope - `currentTheme` and `defaultTheme`. currentTheme is binded to form elements using which user can modify the values of various properties.

```
        var ThemeApp = angular.module('ThemeApp', []);
        ThemeApp.controller('ThemeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("javascripts/myTheme.json").success(function(data) {
                $scope.defaultTheme = data;
                $scope.currentThemes = data;
                console.log($scope.defaultTheme[0]);
            });
            $scope.saveTheme = function() {
                ...
            };
            $scope.resetTheme = function() {
                console.log($scope.defaultTheme);
                $scope.currentThemes = $scope.defaultTheme;
            };
        }]);
```

When we change the values in the form fields then the `defaultTheme` json is also getting changed. I can observe this from console statement in the `resetTheme` function. I have also tried taking `defaultTheme` as a global variable but it also gets changed. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It's not that clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: They are both the same object reference. Make a copy if you don't want them to reference same object/array

Answer (score 1):

You could use lodash to do a cloneDeep of the data object when you assign it to defaultTheme. That way they will start out as the same values but different objects, so when you change the form, it doesn't change the defaults. Code would look like this:

```
$scope.defaultTheme = _.cloneDeep(data);
```